# input to only accept alpha chars (no numbers, or special)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, required

I am trying to **limit a text input field to only accept alphabetical characters *(uppercase and lowercase is fine; but no numbers or special chars)***. I am trying the below for instance:

```
<input id='style-name'type="text" data-value-field="value" name="styleName" required pattern="^[a-z]$"/>
```

What am I doing incorrect here? *Ideally, I would just do this on the HTML side.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add plus `+` sign, to match one or more occurrences of characters typed in input:

```
<input id='style-name'type="text" data-value-field="value" name="styleName" required pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$"/>
```